# Laravel: Sorting a column in the Left Join

Tags: laravel, join, sql-order-by

Lets say I have a simple table of users

`id | userName
3    Michael
4    Mike
5    George`

And another table of their cars and prices

`id | belongsToUser | carPrice
1    4               5000
2    4               6000
3    4               8000`

I would like to do a left join that would return the highest or lowest carPrice
At the moment, the query would return the last/first instance of that users carPrice.
I've tried entering the orderBy in various join queries but to no avail.

I have a helper function that would return the highest/lowest price on demand but I'm not sure how that would fit within this query as I would like to use laravels inbuilt paginate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the aggregate problem so here is the solvation:

```
DB::table('users')
->leftJoin('carPrices', 'belongsToUser', '=', 'users.id')
->select('users.*', DB::raw('MAX(carPrice) as highestCarPrice'), DB::raw('MIN(carPrice) as lowestCarPrice'))
->groupBy('users.id')
->get();
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`` group by `users`.`id`' at line 1 (SQL: select `users`.*, MAX(carPrice) AS highestCarPrice, MIN(carPrice) AS lowestCarPrice from `users` left join `carPrices` on `belongsToUser` =users.id `` group by `users`.`id`)`

Comment: Sory I make an mistake in this code forgot about `table` after `DB::`. Also please check all the names of tables because You didn't post them here.

Comment: Yes I noticed that before executing. Also ; after get()

Comment: Ok I see now. I did another onein leftJoin. I put `.` before `users.id` and it should by `,`.